# Number of primes of type 4*n +1 in a range

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to find number of primes which are congruent 1 (mod 4) in a range [a, b].

The range can be of order $10^9$ as a and b can be from $1$ to $10^9$.

I tried segmented sieve but for a range so large it is taking too much time.

Comment: Do you want the exact number or are approximations allowed?

Comment: exact number is required!

Comment: $10^9$ is not a particularly large range. How much time have you to sieve?